# How can I abstract the schema with jOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I tried to follow the [instructions for mapping a schema in jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.9/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-render-mapping/).

First, I start with a qualified name and table:

```
Name myTableName = DSL.name("schema", "myTable");
Table<Record> myTable = DSL.table(myTableName);
```

Then I build a context with schema mapping:

```
Configuration configuration = new DefaultConfiguration();
configuration.set(SQLDialect.HSQLDB);
Settings settings = new Settings()
    .withRenderNameStyle(RenderNameStyle.QUOTED)
    .withRenderSchema(true)
    .withRenderMapping(
        new RenderMapping()
            .withSchemata(
                new MappedSchema()
                    .withInput("schema")
                    .withOutput("PUBLIC")
            )
    );
configuration.set(settings);
return DSL.using(configuration);
```

Then I build an SQL string to create the table:

```
context.createTable(myTable)....getSQL();
```

But it fails to map the schema:

```
invalid schema name: schema in statement [create table "schema"."myTable"(
    ...
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

For the bigger picture, I'm trying to write SQL that is portable across different dialects, but each of the environments I have to build for uses a different schema. I am trying to abstract a general schema in Java that I can then use jOOQ to map depending on the target environment.

Comment: Is your schema name "schema" is correct?

Comment: "schema" doesn't exist in the database. I'm just using the name as a placeholder to be filled in with the actual schema when I want the SQL string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5344

As of jOOQ 3.9.5, schema mapping and table mapping is not applied to plain SQL tables and custom named tables. While there will not be any mapping applied to plain SQL strings, the latter is fixed as of jOOQ 3.10.

There are two workarounds:

#### You can perform the mapping manually

You're in full control of table reference construction and can map the table explicitly as such:

```java
Name myTableName = DSL.name(schema(), "myTable");
```

And then:

```java
public String schema() {
    if (something)
        return "schema";
    else
        return "PUBLIC";
}
```

#### Use `CustomTable`

A lesser known feature is the [`CustomTable`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-queryparts/) which can be used instead of generated tables if you're not using jOOQ's code generator. It is a bit more effort than a plain SQL table or a named table, but if you can abstract the construction of the table, it might be worth while, because `CustomTable` allows for easily. An example:

```java
public class BookRecord extends CustomRecord<BookRecord> {
    protected BookRecord() {
        super(BookTable.BOOK);
    }
}

public class BookTable extends CustomTable<BookRecord> {
    public static final BookTable                      BOOK       = new BookTable();

    public static final TableField<BookRecord, Short>  ID         
      = createField("ID", SQLDataType.SMALLINT, BOOK);
    public static final TableField<BookRecord, String> TITLE      
      = createField("TITLE", SQLDataType.VARCHAR, BOOK);

    protected BookTable() {
        super("BOOK", DSL.schema(DSL.name("schema")));
    }

    @Override
    public Class<? extends BookRecord> getRecordType() {
        return BookRecord.class;
    }
}
```